# How can the debug module get access to facts on the command line?

Tags: ansible

I dump variables set by `gather_facts` with the setup module, using

```
ansible -u centos -m setup 10.1.38.15
```

But how can I use this on the command line?

This show nothing,

```
ansible -u centos -b -m debug -a "msg='{{ansible_facts}}'" 10.1.38.15
```

And, neither does

```
ansible -u centos -b -m gather_facts -m debug -a "msg='{{ansible_facts}}'" 10.1.38.15
ansible -u centos -b -m setup -m debug -a "msg='{{ansible_facts}}'" 10.1.38.15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run multiple modules at once with  the not-playbook  ansible command.

Either write a short play that gathers facts, and also does things with them.

Or gather facts with an ad-hoc command, but filter it.

```
ansible -m gather_facts  -a filter=ansible_hostname hostpattern
```